# Run the script using hard drive

Tags: r, performance, memory, permutation, hard-drive

Given a set of *n* inputs, I want to generate all permutations of 0's and 1's (essentially the input matrix for a truth table). In order to do so, I am using the permutations command (using the gtools package) in R, as follows:

```
> permutations(2,n,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE)
```

where *n* is the number of inputs.

However, given sufficiently large number of *n* (let's say 26), the size of the variable becomes very high (if n=26, the variable would be approx. 13GB in size). Given this, I wanted to know if there is any way (in R) of using the hard disk instead of creating the variable on the RAM? (I might actually have to run this with *n* = 86 which would be an impossible thing to do on the RAM).

Comment: I'd rather first start thinking on why you want to do this.

Comment: How do you intend on processing through 6.653928e+27 bitstrings?

Comment: @cory     Using a for loop to run over     67108864 rows, and defined a set of condition, in which given particular combination of inputs (with 0 and 1)  will lead to output of 1 or else lead to 0.

Comment: My point is that it's impossible at n=86 and you should work on figuring out an alternative plan

Comment: @cory. I am thinking to break my data into small sets. Could you explain to me, why it is even hard processing my data i.e. 2^86 in hard-drive? It would help to get some insight of what I am trying to do with my data.Thank you

Comment: Let's say you can process 1000 a second. Do the math and see how many seconds it's gonna take to do this. Or work backwards and see how fast you must process each bitstring to get it done in a reasonable amount of time. That's a fantastically large number you are dealing with.